# Упростить выражение php

Tags: php

Чует моё сердце эту строчку можно как-то по-другому записать, чтобы два раза не выполнялась array_search:

```
$begin=array_search($my_uid,$visitor) ? array_search($my_uid,$visitor) : 4;
```

Comment: точно! спасибо

Comment: несколько настораживает, что у вас функция array_search может быть вызвана дважды

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так

```
$begin=array_search($my_uid,$visitor) ? : 4;
```

http://ideone.com/f9FSYx

Comment: В случае с тернарным оператором — лучшее решение.

А вообще, всегда можно помнить, что никто не запрещает использовать присваивание внутри условия:

    if ( ($temp = array_search($my_uid, $visitor)) !== false)
        echo $temp;
    else
        echo 'default: 4';

Вопрос только в удобстве кода.